# How to fix pinch zoom focal point in a custom view?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, scaling, pinchzoom, image-scaling

For my question I have prepared [a very simple test app](https://github.com/afarber/android-questions/tree/master/PinchZoom) at Github.

For simplicity I have removed flinging, scroll constraints and edge effects (which actually work well in my real app):

[image: test app screenshot]

So [the custom view](https://github.com/afarber/android-questions/blob/442b0cb3b5025bad564920ce76521f56dadb6ba4/PinchZoom/app/src/main/java/de/afarber/pinchzoom/MyView.java) in my test app only supports scrolling:

```
mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context,
        new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float dX, float dY) {
        mBoardScrollX -= dX;
        mBoardScrollY -= dY;

        ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(MyView.this);
        return true;
    }
});
```

and pinch zooming with 2 fingers (the focus is broken though!):

```
mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context,
        new ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector scaleDetector) {
        float focusX = scaleDetector.getFocusX();
        float focusY = scaleDetector.getFocusY();
        float factor = scaleDetector.getScaleFactor();

        mBoardScrollX = mBoardScrollX + focusX * (1 - factor) * mBoardScale;
        mBoardScrollY = mBoardScrollY + focusY * (1 - factor) * mBoardScale;
        mBoardScale *= factor;

        ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(MyView.this);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Finally, here the code drawing the scalled and offsetted game board `Drawable`:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.save();
    canvas.scale(mBoardScale, mBoardScale);
    canvas.translate(mBoardScrollX / mBoardScale, mBoardScrollY / mBoardScale);
    mBoard.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

If you try running my app, you will notice that while scaling the game board with two finger pinch zoom gesture works, the zoom focal point jumps around.

My understanding is that while scaling the `Drawable` I need to pan it by adjusting the `mBoardScrollX` and `mBoardScrollY` values - so that the focus point stays at the same point in the game board coordinates. So my calculation is -

The *old* position of that point is:

```
-mBoardScrollX + focusX * mBoardScale
-mBoardScrollY + focusY * mBoardScale
```

and the *new* position would be at:

```
-mBoardScrollX + focusX * mBoardScale * factor
-mBoardScrollY + focusY * mBoardScale * factor
```

By solving these 2 linear equations I get:

```
mBoardScrollX = mBoardScrollX + focusX * (1 - factor) * mBoardScale;
mBoardScrollY = mBoardScrollY + focusY * (1 - factor) * mBoardScale;
```

However that does not work!

To eliminate any errors I have even tried hardcoding the focal point to the middle of my custom view - and still the game board center sways around while scaling:

```
float focusX = getWidth() / 2f;
float focusY = getHeight() / 2f;
```

I think I am missing something minor, please help me.

I would prefer to find a solution without using `Matrix`, because I believe that something really minor is missing in the above calculations. And yes, I have already studied a lot of comparable code, including the [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) by Chris Banes and the [InteractiveChart](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development.git/+/refs/heads/master/samples/training/InteractiveChart/) example by Google.

**DOUBLE TAP UPDATE:**

The `Matrix`-based solution by pskink works very well, however I still have one issue with a wrong focal point -

I have tried to add code to [the custom view](https://github.com/afarber/android-questions/blob/dfcd2ca6622e3b8e41f3f743bbd91b3507812383/PinchZoom/app/src/main/java/de/afarber/pinchzoom/MyView.java) to increase zoom by 100% on a double tap gesture:

```
public boolean onDoubleTap(final MotionEvent e) {
    float[] values = new float[9];
    mMatrix.getValues(values);
    float scale = values[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(scale, 2f * scale);
    animator.setDuration(3000);
    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator){
            float scale = (float) animator.getAnimatedValue();
            mMatrix.setScale(scale, scale, e.getX(), e.getY());
            ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(MyView.this);
        }
    });
    animator.start();
    return true;
}
```

And while the zoom changes correctly, the focal point is wrong again - even though the focal point coordinates are passed to each `setScale` call.

For example when I double tap in the middle of the screen, the result will be panned too far right and down:

[image: emulator screenshot]

Comment: too much math imho, `Matrix` would be really better, see `Canvas.concat` method which shows how easily you can do some nice things without that math and `Canvas.scale` / `Canvas.translate` / `Canvas.rotate` calls, BTW nice looking ui ;-)

Comment: for example [this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pskink/92aa3f8d74c15509d5d0b25fd431c008/raw/40a58d4d9503dcdf319c9a7544d56400d26a4793/Sizer.java) gist is a nice example - return some `ImageView` from `getMainView` method to see it in action

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions (+1) I will try this on the weekend again (tried before and failed). Also, I have a feeling that only a minor thing is missing in the non-`Matrix` approach and am curious what is wrong in [my simple test app](https://github.com/afarber/android-questions/blob/master/PinchZoom/app/src/main/java/de/afarber/pinchzoom/MyView.java).

Comment: Yes, your code is simpler and works perfectly. Do you want to submit it as an answer, so that I can award you the bounty? I still have an open question though: how to constrain certain zoom and scroll limits? Should I use `mMatrix.getValues()`? And I wonder if I should save all 9 float values in the `onRestoreInstanceState` or maybe less will do?

Comment: Yes, that [has worked](https://github.com/afarber/android-questions/blob/master/PinchZoom/app/src/main/java/de/afarber/pinchzoom/MyView.java), thank you. I would like to try an `DecelerateInterpolator+onDraw()` solution too, without the `ValueAnimator`

Comment: Thank you, I agree that 1.005f is strange, will try a solution without `ValueAnimator` soon...

Comment: no, no, no, `ValueAnimator` is good, simply use `scaleFactor = newScale / oldScale` thats it, but ok, maybe i would use `ObjectAnimator` - it gives less boilerplate code

Comment: Thank you, I have [rewritten my ValueAnimator](https://github.com/afarber/android-questions/tree/master/PinchZoom/app/src/main/java/de/afarber/pinchzoom) to change gradually between oldScale and newScale (do not want to use `ObjectAnimator` because of reflection)

Comment: Thanks so much - now I am ready to improve zooming in the custom view of [my real app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.slova). By the way it is in Russian now, but I have prepared a dictionary with 133376 Dutch words too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `Matrix` is a *really* better idea - the code is much more simple and you dont have to prove your math skills ;-), see how `Matrix#postTranslate` and `Matrix#postScale` methods are used:

```
class MyView extends View {
    private static final String TAG = "MyView";

    private final ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    private final GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    private final Drawable mBoard;
    private final float mBoardWidth;
    private final float mBoardHeight;
    private Matrix mMatrix;

    public MyView(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        mBoard = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(), R.drawable.chrome, null);
        mBoardWidth = mBoard.getIntrinsicWidth();
        mBoardHeight = mBoard.getIntrinsicHeight();
        mBoard.setBounds(0, 0, (int) mBoardWidth, (int) mBoardHeight);

        mMatrix = new Matrix();

        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, scaleListener);
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, listener);
    }

    ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener scaleListener = new ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector scaleDetector) {
            float factor = scaleDetector.getScaleFactor();
            mMatrix.postScale(factor, factor, getWidth() / 2f, getHeight() / 2f);
            ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(MyView.this);
            return true;
        }
    };

    GestureDetector.OnGestureListener listener = new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float dX, float dY) {
            mMatrix.postTranslate(-dX, -dY);
            ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(MyView.this);
            return true;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        float scale = Math.max(w / mBoardWidth, h / mBoardHeight);
        mMatrix.setScale(scale, scale);
        mMatrix.postTranslate((w - scale * mBoardWidth) / 2f, (h - scale * mBoardHeight) / 2f);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save();
        canvas.concat(mMatrix);
        mBoard.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e);
        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(e);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly. Do you please have any advice on enforcing zoom/scroll limits, is there some Matrix trick for that? (EDIT: thanks for the `mapRect` advice) And how would you implement zooming on double tap, should I use something like [Zoomer](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development.git/+/refs/heads/master/samples/training/InteractiveChart/src/com/example/android/interactivechart/Zoomer.java) or is there something easier?

Comment: simple `ValueAnimator` will do that (if you want smooth zoom-in/zoom-out) on double click

Comment: Good morning @pskink could you please take one last look at my updated question? When I try to implement double tap zooming and repeatedly call `mMatrix.setScale(scale, scale, e.getX(), e.getY());` in a `ValueAnimator` listener, the focal point is wrong again for some reason.

Comment: `setScale` clears translation, use `postScale` instead

Comment: I did try `postScale` before, but get a completely white custom view for some reason when the following code is called by the ValueAnimator: `mMatrix.postScale(scale, scale, e.getX(), e.getY());`

Comment: Oh, is it [a rice and chessboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheat_and_chessboard_problem) problem? The `scale` multiplies with itself multiple time?

Comment: yes: if you want to scale from 1 to 2 in 10 steps then you need to use 1.1/1.0 the first time, 1.2/1.1 the second time 1.3/1.2 the third time etc - or at least it seems so... - this is the place where you can use your MATH SKILLS ;-)